# C using pragma omp Problem with time optimization

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to run this code on parallel, to optimize the "wall clock time"

Running it without any changes its around 0.00775 sec

The original segment of the code:

```
for (it=1;it<=itmax;it++)
  {
    dphimax=0.;
    for (k=1;k<kmax;k++)
    {
      for (i=1;i<imax;i++)
      {
        dphi=(phi[i+1][k]+phi[i-1][k]-2.*phi[i][k])*dy2i
            +(phi[i][k+1]+phi[i][k-1]-2.*phi[i][k])*dx2i;
        dphi=dphi*dt;
        dphimax=max(dphimax,dphi);
        phin[i][k]=phi[i][k]+dphi;
      }
    }
/* save values */
    for (k=1;k<kmax;k++)
    {
      for (i=1;i<imax;i++)
      {
    phi[i][k]=phin[i][k];
      }
    }
    if(dphimax<eps) break;
  }

  t2=clock();
# ifdef _OPENMP
    wt2=omp_get_wtime();
# endif
  gettimeofday(&tv2, &tz);

  printf("\nphi after %d iterations\n",it);
  heatpr(phi);
  printf( "CPU time (clock)                = %12.4g sec\n", (t2-t1)/1000000.0 );
# ifdef _OPENMP
    printf( "wall clock time (omp_get_wtime) = %12.4g sec\n", wt2-wt1 );
# endif
  printf( "wall clock time (gettimeofday)  = %12.4g sec\n", (tv2.tv_sec-tv1.tv_sec) + (tv2.tv_usec-tv1.tv_usec)*1e-6 );

}
```

When I try to use openmp to optimize, it only make it worse.

The wall clock time goes up to around 0.01644 sec, i dont know what am i doing wrong?

did this:

```
  #pragma omp parallel private(it, k, i), shared(phi, phin, dy2i, dx2i, dphi) //tried also with shared(dphi, dphimax, phi, phin)
  {
  for (it=1;it<=itmax;it++)
  { 
    dphimax=0.;
    //pragma omp parallel for
    for (k=1;k<kmax;k++)
    {
      for (i=1;i<imax;i++)
      {
        dphi=(phi[i+1][k]+phi[i-1][k]-2.*phi[i][k])*dy2i
            +(phi[i][k+1]+phi[i][k-1]-2.*phi[i][k])*dx2i;
        dphi=dphi*dt;
        dphimax=max(dphimax,dphi);
        phin[i][k]=phi[i][k]+dphi;
      }
    }
```

How can i optimize this?

Comment: Even if you use OpenMP properly on this example, it is possible that you won't see much speedup on such a small test case. There is some overhead with parallelisation and when things take fractions of a second it may represent a substantial fraction of the total execution time.

Comment: @Carol you should not need that barrier, did you increase the input size? btw can you share a link to the code to see what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> Running it without any changes its around 0.00775 sec

To really see the benefits of the parallelism you need to increase your input size. Otherwise, the computation being performed in parallel will not be enough to overcome the additional overhead introduced with the parallelism (e.g., thread creation and synchronization)

Let us start by declaring the variables closer to the scope where they will used. This will avoid having to explicitly add OpenMP pragmas to make those variables private (*i.e.,* `private(it, k, i)`)

```
double dphimax;
for (it=1;it<=itmax;it++){    
    dphimax=0.0;
    for (k=1;k<kmax;k++){
       for (i=1;i<imax;i++){
          dphi=(phi[i+1][k]+phi[i-1][k]-2.*phi[i][k])*dy2i
              +(phi[i][k+1]+phi[i][k-1]-2.*phi[i][k])*dx2i;
          dphi=dphi*dt;
          dphimax=max(dphimax,dphi);
          phin[i][k]=phi[i][k]+dphi;
      }
   }
    for (k=1;k<kmax;k++)
      for (i=1;i<imax;i++)
          phi[i][k]=phin[i][k];
    if(dphimax<eps) break;
}
```

For the parallel region we can try to add the entire chunk of code:

```
double dphimax;
#pragma omp parallel
for (it=1;it<=itmax;it++){    
    ....
}
```

Now let us look of which loops iterations can be divided among threads. The outermost loop would not work because there are dependencies between its iterations. The next candidate, is the loop:

```
for (k=1;k<kmax;k++){
   for (i=1;i<imax;i++){
      dphi=(phi[i+1][k]+phi[i-1][k]-2.*phi[i][k])*dy2i
          +(phi[i][k+1]+phi[i][k-1]-2.*phi[i][k])*dx2i;
      dphi=dphi*dt;
      dphimax=max(dphimax,dphi);
      phin[i][k]=phi[i][k]+dphi;
  }
```

}

To parallelize this one we need to fix the race-condition on the updates of the variable `dphimax`, for that we can use the `reduction` clause of OpenMP:

```
  #pragma omp for reduction(max: dphimax)
  for (int k=1; k<kmax; k++){
     for (int i=1; i<imax ;i++){
       double dphi=(phi[i+1][k]+phi[i-1][k]-2.*phi[i][k])*dy2i +
                   (phi[i][k+1]+phi[i][k-1]-2.*phi[i][k])*dx2i;
       dphi = dphi * dt;
       dphimax = max(dphimax, dphi);
       phin[i][k] = phi[i][k] + dphi;
     }
 }
```

We can also parallelize the last loop:

```
#pragma omp for
for (k=1;k<kmax;k++)
  for (i=1;i<imax;i++)
      phi[i][k]=phin[i][k];
```

You can also play around with vectorizing it instead:

```
#pragma omp simd
for (k=1;k<kmax;k++)
  for (i=1;i<imax;i++)
      phi[i][k]=phin[i][k];
```

Everything put together:

```
double dphimax;
#pragma omp parallel
for (it=1;it<=itmax;it++){    
    dphimax=0.0;
    #pragma omp for reduction(max: dphimax)
    for (k=1;k<kmax;k++){
       for (i=1;i<imax;i++){
          dphi=(phi[i+1][k]+phi[i-1][k]-2.*phi[i][k])*dy2i
              +(phi[i][k+1]+phi[i][k-1]-2.*phi[i][k])*dx2i;
          dphi=dphi*dt;
          dphimax=max(dphimax,dphi);
          phin[i][k]=phi[i][k]+dphi;
      }
   }
    #pragma omp for
    for (k=1;k<kmax;k++)
      for (i=1;i<imax;i++)
          phi[i][k]=phin[i][k];
    if(dphimax<eps) break;
}
```